# IE9 CSS float margin bug

Tags: css, css-float

Hi I have this working upper menu section in Chrome/firefox and proper browsers, but its broken in IE 9 in the searchbar/social icon header area.

***edits to help crappiness of this post, sorry :(***

This is now what the header HTML looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

http://radiantrfid.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your headers to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

And remove the two first empty lines : the doctype should be on the first one.

This will make IE respect the standards and work like other browsers.

Comment: SWEET! this got me much closer, now compatibility view looks nearly right. I didnt change it all like you recommeneded but I did add the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` and that looked to solve a lot of the problems. Now its just the social icons that are floating weird